# Приложение возвращает NULL

Tags: android-sdk, android, java, json

Доброго времени суток.

Столкнулся с проблемой и не знаю, в чем может быть причина. Написал код получения JSON данных на Андроид с сайта, эмулятор Андроида получает весь JSON, скомпилированное и закачанное на реальное устройство приложение возвращает вместо JSON - NULL. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Покажите код.

Comment: Показывал, уважаемый модератор стер его. Надеюсь ссылка разрешена http://pastebin.com/KANbK8LD

Comment: >Показывал, уважаемый модератор стер его

не в первый раз замечаю, что уважаемый модератор @Виталина чересчур много себе позволяет в плане модерации, удаляя или редактируя важные для понимания вопроса и его решения ответы и комментарии. Очень хотелось бы поинтересоваться у уважаемого модератора об основаниях для подобных действий и логике принятия таких не бесспорных решений

Comment: Присоединяюсь к ответу пользователя @Gorets. Почитайте про AsyncTask. Вот [>пример<][1].


  [1]: https://docs.google.com/document/d/15eF2YQtrprJQgqdokbqhYobRbYuIq5LIeWRfetK6Xf4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @DreamChild, так более того, модерирует с ошибками, пунктуационными точно, надеюсь хоть с грамматикой все хорошо. 
@Виталина ♦ может прокомментируете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начиная с 11 версии `API`, `(Android 3.0)` выполнять ресурсоемкие задачи (например, работа с сетью) в главном потоке нельзя.

Для решения этой проблемы используют *многопоточность*.
Платформа предоставляет класс [Thread](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/thread.php) и [AsyncTask](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/asynctask.php) (возможно еще что то есть, но мои знания этим ограничиваются).

Т.е. вам нужно создать отдельный поток, и в нём выполонить свою задачу.

Answer (score 0):

код не смотрел, пользуюсь только экстрасенсорикой, но думаю что проблема в манифесте, а если точнее в отсутствии прав на интернет, вероятней всего что эмуляторы они не нужны...

зы посмотрел код, 2я причина - работа с сетью должны быть в потоке, а у тебя в UI...

Comment: В Манифесте есть разрешение на интернет и эмулятору он тоже важен, а вот насчет работы с сетью в потоке не могли бы вы выложить код, ибо я совсем новичок и не знаю как это. Спасибо.